# Using lblClass.expression to outline labels in ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, labeling

I'd like to add outlines to my labels using ArcPy. This *seems* simple enough by modifying Esri's Background [text formatting tag](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm), but I haven't been able to make it work.

My code works just fine (minus the needed text outlines), here's a sample:

```
import arcpy, os, sys
relpath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(os.path.join(relpath+"CURRENT"))
lyr = m.listLayers()[0]

#Label LAYER with Ariel, 10pt font, white text
#Make symbols white circles, size 12
    for lyr in m.listLayers(LAYER):
        sym = lyr.symbology
        lblClass = lyr.listLabelClasses()[0]
        print(lblClass.name)
        lblClass.expression = "\"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '10'>\" + \"<CLR red = '255' green = '255' blue = '255'>\" + $feature.SERIALNO + \"</CLR>\" +  \"</FNT>\""
        lyr.showLabels = True
        sym.renderer.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery("Overhead")
        sym.renderer.symbol.size = 12
        lyr.symbology = sym
        p.saveACopy(os.path.join(relpath+"CURRENT"))
```

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

I guess its down to you and tags that you had used. Here is a minimal amount of code that places an outline to a label.

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr = m.listLayers()[0]
lblClass = lyr.listLabelClasses()[0]
lblClass.expression = "\"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '10'>\" + \"<CLR red = '255' green = '255' blue = '255'>\" + \"<BGD red = '25' green = '25' blue = '25' padding = '3' width = '1' >\" +  $feature.Type +\"</BGD>\" +  \"</CLR>\" +  \"</FNT>\""
lyr.showLabels = True
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The code seems to make the label a sort of tag. I'll tweak it and put the result here.

Comment: Thanks for your help Hornbydd, unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't seem to work!

Comment: What does not work? Works for me.

Comment: The code creates a box around the text, no matter how I modify the padding and width numbers. Nothing that I have tried works yet! Would you mind posting more of your code? Perhaps I did something wrong higher up.